# ffmpeg from .mp3 to .al appears to slow and deepen the audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an mp3 input file that is 22050Hz and 48kb/s. I need to convert it to a .al file in order to stream it to a camera on my network for output.

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3 file.al
```

creates a file that does play but the bitrate of the output is 176kb/s and it clearly slower/deeper sounding. I have tried -b:a 48k and -filter:a without success but I could be doing it wrong.

Documentation states that this is the format I need: PCM ADPCM G.711A G.711.Mu G.726 G.729 MPEG2 AMR AAC

Comment: Bitrate isn't the problem.... *sample rate* is.

Comment: Yep. Rough day.

Comment: Cheers, friend.  I hope your days in the near future are not rough!

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ar 8000 -ac 1 -ab 64 output.al -ar 8000 -ac 1 -ab 64 -f mulaw
```

This has produced the correct result. Conversion is for playing audio over an Amcrest camera speaker.